# Using React.js to show/hide modal not working

Tags: reactjs

Here is my modal component:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';

const Modal = React.createClass({
    handleOverlayClick () {
        this.setState({ showModal: false });
    },

    shouldComponentUpdate (newProps, newState) {
        return newState.showModal !== this.props.showModal;
    },

    render () {
        const style = {
            display: (this.props.showModal) ? 'block' : 'none'
        };

        console.log(style);

        return (
            <div className="modal-overlay" style={style}>
                <div className="modal-container" onClick={this.handleOverlayClick}>
                    <div className="modal-content modal-input">Hello, world</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Modal;
```

And this is how I am calling it:

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SplitButton from './split-button';
import EmmaButton from './emma-button';
import SelectEmailModal from './modals/email-select.modal';

const AddActionBtn = React.createClass({

    onClick () {
        return "#";
    },

    handleSendMailing () {
        return ReactDOM.render(<SelectEmailModal showModal={true} />, document.getElementById('modals'));
    },

    handleWait() {
        console.log("WAIT");
        return "#";
    },

    render () {
        return (
            <SplitButton primaryLabel="ADD ACTION &#9660;" primaryAction={this.onClick}>
                <ul>
                    <li><span onClick={this.handleSendMailing}>Send mailing</span></li>
                    <li><span onClick={this.handleWait}>Wait</span></li>
                </ul>
            </SplitButton>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AddActionBtn;
```

I am a newb to React so excuse my ignorance here. Just wanting to simply Show/Hide a modal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the error is here?
`display: (this.props.showModal) ? 'block' : 'none'`

showModal is a state, not a prop, so:
`this.state.showModal`

Comment: Ah, I'll need to go back and do some more research on the two

Comment: `<App text="Hello World">`: text is a prop inside component App, so you call `this.props.text`. But when you `this.state = {text: 'Hello World!'}` you refer to it as `this.state.text`